# visual studio gui to control stepper motor

Tags: arduino, motor, stepper-motor, electro-mechanical

I am using visual studio 2019 and wants to build gui to give commands like speed to control stepper motor through arduino.  I am new to visual studio. can someone share code or can explain?
Thanks

Comment: Please capitalise proper nouns (brand names, etc.) and initialisations properly in the title and the post. It helps legibility and makes it clear what you are referring to. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: [Visual Studio Arduino GUI](https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+Studio+Arduino+GUI&oq=Visual+Studio+Arduino+GUI)